# Bootstrap dropdown menu not scrolling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having some trouble with a dropdown menu I'm using at [louiseballantine.com/redesign/bridal.php](http://www.louiseballantine.com/redesign/bridal.php).

On smaller screens where the collapsed menu is shown, you'll notice that the menu seems to work well at first. However, when you activate the **Bridal & Occasion** sub-menu, there is a scrolling issue and part of the menu cannot be accessed.

Admittedly, Bootstrap is new to me and I get a little lost when trying to pick my way through the many styles associated with the various menus, but I've tried adding/editing various **max-height** and **overflow** declarations with no success.

One thing which also annoys me slightly is that the menu seems to operate based on **:hover** rather than when clicked. I'd like to fix this too.

Please excuse my inexperience. Any advice or assistance would be very gratefully received.

::::: UPDATE :::::

It seems I've been unclear regarding the issue with scrolling. This only seems to be apparent on handheld devices. On my iPhone, for example, the menu seems fine at first, but when you open the **Bridal & Occasion** sub-menu, it becomes impossible to see anything below **Gallery**.

Again, I've played around with the various **max-height** and **overflow** settings, but can't seem to locate the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

::: Navbar HTML :::

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="width:100%;">
    <li class="hidden">
      <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="bridal.php" target="_self" id="homenav">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php" target="_self" id="aboutnav">Bio</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" id="bridalnav" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Bridal &amp; Occasion <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
        <li><a href="bridalmakeup.php" target="_self" id="makeupnav">Bridal Makeup</a></li>
        <li><a href="makeuplessons.php" target="_self" id="lessonsnav">Makeup Lessons</a></li>
        <li><a href="occasionmakeup.php" target="_self" id="occasionnav">Occasion &amp; Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="hairextensions.php" target="_self" id="extensionsnav">Hair Extensions</a></li>
        <li><a href="spraytanning.php" target="_self" id="tanningnav">Spray Tanning</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="bridalgallery.php" target="_self" id="gallerynav">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="makeuptutorialvideos.php" target="_self" id="videossnav">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="reviews.php" target="_self" id="testimonialsnav">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="rates.php" target="_self" id="ratesnav">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" target="_self" id="contactnav">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

::: Navbar CSS (Bootstrap) :::

```
.dropdown {position: relative;}
.dropdown-toggle:focus {outline: 0;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;}

.dropdown-menu {
/*position: absolute;*/
position: relative;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1100;
display: none;
float: left;
/*min-width: 20em;*/
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 1em 0;
font-size: 1em;
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
background-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 20em;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
}
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #111;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.95);
}
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #666;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
}
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(40,40,40,1.0);
  outline: 0;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
  outline: 0;
}
}
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #777;
}
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
}
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.open > a {
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu-left {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}
.dropdown-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #777;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 990;
}
.pull-right > .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropup .caret,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .caret {
  content: "";
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
.dropup .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
  }
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu-left {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.nav > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #999;
}
.nav > li.disabled > a {
  color: #777;
}
.nav > li.disabled > a:hover,
.nav > li.disabled > a:focus {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-color: #428bca;
}
.nav .nav-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.nav > li > a > img {
  max-width: none;
}
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #eee #eee #ddd;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
}
.nav-pills > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-stacked > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-justified > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-justified > li > a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-justified > .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-justified > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
.nav-tabs-justified {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs-justified > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-tabs-justified > .active > a,
.nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .nav-tabs-justified > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  }
  .nav-tabs-justified > .active > a,
  .nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs-justified > .active > a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}
.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
  }
}
.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#eee;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
  max-height: none; /* was 340px */
}
@media (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: none; /* was 240px */
  }
}

.navbar-static-top {
  z-index: 1000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
/* Media Query increased from 767px to 769px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-left {
    float: left !important;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
.navbar-form {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
  .navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
    width: auto;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group > .form-control {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-form .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio,
  .navbar-form .checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio label,
  .navbar-form .checkbox label {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio input[type="radio"],
  .navbar-form .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0;
  }
}
/* Media Query increased from 767px to 769px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-form {
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-form.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-btn {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.navbar-btn.btn-sm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-btn.btn-xs {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.navbar-text {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  .navbar-text {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-text.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #5e5e5e;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #666;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #666;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #333;
}
/* Media Query increased from 767px to 769px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .btn-link {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
  color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
  color: #ccc;
}
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #080808;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #080808;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #444;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #333;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #333;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: #101010;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #080808;
}
/* Media Query increased from 767px to 769px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-header {
    border-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #080808;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-link {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .btn-link {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
  color: #444;
}
```

::: Navbar CSS (Agency Theme) :::

```
#navigation {/*border:1px solid #CCC;*/ margin:0; padding:0;}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Oswald', serif;
    color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand.active {
    color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    /*border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.02)*/;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #333;
}

.navbar-default .nav li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav li a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#333;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
}

/* Media Query increased from 768px to 770px to account for Portrait iPad */
@media (min-width: 770px) {
.navbar-default .nav li a {
    color: #000;
}
.navbar-default .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav li a:focus {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color:#000;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
}
}

@media(min-width:770px) {
    .navbar-default {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
        -moz-transition: padding .3s;
        transition: padding .3s;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 2em;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .navbar-default.navbar-shrink {
        padding: 10px 0;
        background-color: #222;
    }

    .navbar-default.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}
```

::: Custom CSS :::

```
@media (min-width: 770px) {
.navbar-collapse {background:#FFF;}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(210,210,210,.95);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
}
```

Comment: Kevin I have not tried this code, but i had seen this link https://www.gaslampmedia.com/multilevel-dropdown-menus-bootstrap-3-x/ sometime back which tells how to resolve the multilevel dropdown issue. Maybe you would find this useful.

Comment: Works for me - using Chrome on Mac OS X - i am able to see all menu items on a reduced window